# Open modal popup from another page

Tags: javascript, php, html

So in my website I have a navigation bar. The first "button" on that bar opens a [modal pop box](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp). That modal box is created from 4500 lines. Can I add the modal box code to another page (for example `modalView.php`) and open that up from `index.php`, **without** leaving index.php?

Comment: You can definitely extract it out to another page, make an ajax request to get it upon demand, and then use it.

Comment: @Taplar Would that be the same as using iframe? Or do you suggest Ajax over iframe?

Comment: You can stick an iframe in a modal, but if you are going to do that, I'd just make an ajax request and put the response in the modal.  But, bottom line, that's just my opinion

Comment: You can use your favorite search engine to search for "Javascript, ajax" or "Javascript, fetch".  There should be plenty of available example to break apart and learn from.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an `iframe` in your modal. An html iframe is used to display an external webpage on another, so just put an `iframe` in your modal, for example, `<iframe src="/somepage.html"></iframe>`. You can style this `iframe`, (i.e. width, height) using CSS.

Comment: How can I open iframe when pressing `a href` link?

Comment: you can use target, i.e. <a href="somepage.html" target=yourIframeId"></a>.

Comment: But for a modal, you can just put the iframe in your modal.

Comment: I personally think this is the most simple method.

Comment: You can see more here: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

i think you can open the popup modal using boostrap.
And put the iframe url inside the modal.
So you can prevent to leaving index.php.
Here is a little example:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
  Iframe inside modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <!-- change the src -->
        <iframe width="100%" hight="auto" src="https://stackoverflow.com/">
</iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</html>
```

Modal Boostrap
[References](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Hope it help. Thankyou!